# How to control which cluster kubectl talks to?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, microk8s

I'm using kubectl to control a local microk8s installation. I configured a local Google cloud shell connection in order to avoid the ridiculous provisioning of the machine available through the GKE dashboard.

Now, `kubectl` commands seem to be randomly executed on microk8s and GKE. I want not only to fix this, but prohibit this scenario for the future.

The possibility that `kubectl` can refer to different environment is a horrible idea apparently founded in concept of the `kubectl` CLI which provides no way to specify a remote cluster. It can lead to accidental changes on production systems. Even a hardcore 12-factor evangelist will have a local cluster installed for development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kubectl config use-context` command can be used to modify, whom kubectl talks to.

> configure access to multiple clusters by using configuration files. After your clusters, users, and contexts are defined in one or more configuration files, you can quickly switch between clusters by using the.
>   [configure-access-multiple-clusters/](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/)

Comment: Use `kubectl config get-contexts` to list the configured clusters

Comment: Check [k](https://gitlab.com/kubic-ci/k) if you are looking for a short-hand to switch cluster context as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57860864/544463

Answer (score 0):

You may supply/add `--context` and `--namespace` options to your `kubectl` command to run `kubectl` against any cluster. Is is handy if you work with multiple clusters back and forth at the same time.

```
kubectl --cluster=my_cluster --namespace=my_namespace get pods
```

> Note: Please change cluster & namespace names for your environment.

Here are more kubectl options:

```
~/git/kubernetes (master) $ kubectl options
The following options can be passed to any command:

  --alsologtostderr=false: log to standard error as well as files
  --as='': Username to impersonate for the operation
  --as-group=[]: Group to impersonate for the operation, this flag can be repeated to specify multiple groups.
  --cache-dir='/Users/robertrt/.kube/http-cache': Default HTTP cache directory
  --certificate-authority='': Path to a cert file for the certificate authority
  --client-certificate='': Path to a client certificate file for TLS
  --client-key='': Path to a client key file for TLS
  --cluster='': The name of the kubeconfig cluster to use
  --context='': The name of the kubeconfig context to use
  --insecure-skip-tls-verify=false: If true, the server's certificate will not be checked for validity. This will make your HTTPS connections insecure
  --kubeconfig='': Path to the kubeconfig file to use for CLI requests.
  --log-backtrace-at=:0: when logging hits line file:N, emit a stack trace
  --log-dir='': If non-empty, write log files in this directory
  --log-flush-frequency=5s: Maximum number of seconds between log flushes
  --logtostderr=true: log to standard error instead of files
  --match-server-version=false: Require server version to match client version
-n, --namespace='': If present, the namespace scope for this CLI request
  --request-timeout='0': The length of time to wait before giving up on a single server request. Non-zero values should contain a corresponding time unit (e.g. 1s, 2m, 3h). A value of zero means don't timeout requests.
-s, --server='': The address and port of the Kubernetes API server
  --stderrthreshold=2: logs at or above this threshold go to stderr
  --token='': Bearer token for authentication to the API server
  --user='': The name of the kubeconfig user to use
-v, --v=0: log level for V logs
  --vmodule=: comma-separated list of pattern=N settings for file-filtered logging
```